# Android studio 2.2.0.12 does not showing cloud option in project structure

Tags: android

I went to the Tool->firebase. And connect my android application to the firebase but I am writing the code in the onCreate method (code- Firebase.setAndroidContex(this)) it showing an error that cannot  resolve this symbol.Please make it clear

Answer (score 0):

android studio 2.2.0 at now not use Firebase.setAndroidContext() this function.they are use

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

need to update sdk manager
 1. update google play service
 2. and compile the latest Firebase library